# Parse Objects not retrieved nor presented in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am querying parse objects from a relation pointer, and then presenting those objects in a UITableview. However, whenever I use my code to query nothing shows up and it is just blank. I have used this code before to query objects from parse but not from a relation. Any help on how to query it and present it would greatly be appreciated.

```
 class MyGroupsHomePage: UITableViewController {

let cellidentifer = "MyGroupsCell"


var mygroupsdata: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func findcurrentuserobjects () {
    var currentuser = PFUser.query()
    currentuser!.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    currentuser!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && object != nil {

            if let object = object as? [PFObject] {

                for objects in object {

                  let relation = objects.relationForKey("UserGroups")
                    let query = relation.query()
                    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (ob: [AnyObject]?, er: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if er == nil && ob != nil {

                            if let ob = ob as? [PFObject] {
                                for obs in ob {
                                    self.mygroupsdata.addObject(obs)
                                }
                            }      
                        }

                    })   
                }
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()   
    }    
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    findcurrentuserobjects() 
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.mygroupsdata.count
}
```

The `GroupName` object represents the column of objects I want to retrieve from the relation.

```
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
      let mygroupdata: PFObject = self.mygroupsdata.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
      cell.textLabel?.text = mygroupdata.objectForKey("GroupName")! as? String

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `self.tableView.reloadData()` there is no data added to `mygroupsdata` yet, because `query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous function that returns immediately. The callback that adds objects to mygroupsdata is excuted after you reload the tableview. Try to reload the tableview here:

```
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (ob: [AnyObject]?, er: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if er == nil && ob != nil {

                        if let ob = ob as? [PFObject] {
                            for obs in ob {
                                self.mygroupsdata.addObject(obs)
                            }
                        } 
                        self.tableView.reloadData()      
                    }

                })
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works beautifully!